# Radeon Pro Render Adds-On Wont Active

Tags: radeon-prorender-render-engine

I downloaded the Radeon Pro Render And installed it, but when I'm trying to activate it inside blender it'll give me this error?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess, what Os are you using and is there an OS specific version available ? Also, what version do you use ? Some addons broke in 2.92 because of an upgrade in python version

Comment: I'm using windows 10 latest version and the latest version of blender ( 2.93.1 ) and Radeon Pro Render, I downloaded the plugin directly from the AMD website

Comment: Try version 2.92 maybe